# retrieve current user data from the firebase

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, macos

let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("Employess").child(userId!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

```
       // Get user value
       let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       //print(value)

let Name = value?["name"] as? String
        print(Name)
        // ...
        }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)


   }
```

Comment: i get the value of 'print(Name)' as nil instead the value of name in my firebasedatabase

Comment: Please edit the question with that additional information instead of adding it in a comment.  You would also help the community assist you if you provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: We probably need to see your Firebase structure to know what's wrong but are you sure that your database has a key called "Employess" not "Employees" or "Employers". That could be the problem.